# onPostHandler extension not called when an error is thrown in the handler

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm upgrading from hapi14 to hapi17, when throwing or returning an error inside a handler onPostHandlers are not called, this isn't listed as a breaking change in either 16 or 17.

I believe this is a result of changing from callbacks to async but i'd love to get it confirmed or find out what the problem is that is preventing the onPostHandler extension being called in the event of an error being throw in the handler.

```
const Boom = require('boom');

const extensions = {
  handleOnPostHandler: function (request, h) {
    console.log('we hit it wooo');
    return h.continue;
  }
};

const operations = {
  error: {
    description: 'Endpoint that simulates errors',
    auth: false,
    handler: function (request, h) {
      // comment me out to call the onPostHandler
      throw new Boom('an error');

      // uncomment me to call the onPostHandler
      // return 'potato';
    }
  }
};

exports.register = function (server) {
  server.ext('onPostHandler', extensions.handleOnPostHandler);
  server.route({ method: 'GET', path: '/debug/error', config: operations.error });
};
```

Is there a gross mistake i'm missing or is this expected?

Comment: I have a workaround using onPreResponse which i'll answer this question with if it doesn't receive a good answer within a few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an undocumented feature that was removed in [Hapi6](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3398) and as such when upgrading to >16 this functionality cannot be emulated.

Answer (score -1):

because you are throwing an error before request come to an end? Just return from your handler then your `handleOnPostHandler` will be called.

On the list of [life cycle methods](https://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle) it says

> Route handler
>
> > executes the route handler.
>
> onPostHandler
>
> > the response contained in request.response may be modified (but not
> >     assigned a new value). To return a different response type (for
> >     example, replace an error with an HTML response), return a new
> >     response value.

But you are not allowing your handler move on to onPostHandler, you are throwing an error. It takeovers the response.

Comment: If you return a Boom you will still skip the onPostHandler.

Comment: that was what i said.

Comment: No it isn't. You've said to return from the handler, if i return an error, which is what i want to do in this case, i cannot access the onPostHandler. This worked previously in Hapi14.